# How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node?

Tags: git

fs.js:35
} = primordials;
^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:35:5
at req_ (D:\tutorials\corsera\bootstrap4\confusion\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (D:\tutorials\corsera\bootstrap4\confusion\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object. (D:\tutorials\corsera\bootstrap4\confusion\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)

Comment: im using node verison- 12.16.1 and gulp version- 3.9.1..then tell me how to overcome from this error?

Comment: This question appears to be mis-tagged. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git, not NodeJS and its ecosystems.